# Golang: http proxy server to multiple endpoints based on some conditions

Tags: go, http, proxy

I need to do some logic: proxy server that listen on port is receiving a request. It is always POST, and payload is always XML. I need to look inside it, and based on some conditions (XML tag values) i need to send original request to first or second backend.
I have something like this using standard http package, and it works - sometimes:

```
func main() {
[...]
    server := &http.Server{
        Handler:     h,
        ReadTimeout: time.Duration(*globalTimeout) * time.Millisecond,
    }

    log.Printf("Proxy engine ready and listen at %s, global timeout: %d ms", *listenAddress, *globalTimeout)
    log.Fatalln(server.Serve(listener))
[...]
}

func (h handler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var requestBody []byte
    if r.Body != nil {
        requestBody, _ = io.ReadAll(r.Body)
    }
    // rewind request body
    r.Body = io.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(requestBody))

    relevantValues := getRelevantValues(requestBody)
    if checkCondition(relevantValues) {
        log.Println("Proxying request to endpoint 1")
        r.URL = h.Target1
    } else {
        log.Println("Proxying request to endpoint 2")
        r.URL = h.Target2
    }

    timeout := time.Duration(time.Duration(*globalTimeout).Milliseconds())
    resp := handleRequest(r, timeout, r.URL.Scheme)

    if resp != nil {
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        log.Printf("%s %s %v, %s", r.Method, r.URL.String(), r.Proto, resp.Status)

        // Forward response headers
        for k, v := range resp.Header {
            w.Header()[k] = v
        }
        w.WriteHeader(resp.StatusCode)

        // Forward response body
        io.Copy(w, resp.Body)
    } else {
        log.Printf("Response is nil :(")
    }
}

func handleRequest(request *http.Request, timeout time.Duration, scheme string) *http.Response {
    var transport *http.Transport

    if scheme == "https" {
        transport = &http.Transport{
            DialContext:           (&net.Dialer{Timeout: timeout, KeepAlive: 10 * timeout}).DialContext,
            DisableKeepAlives:     *closeConnections,
            TLSHandshakeTimeout:   timeout,
            ResponseHeaderTimeout: timeout,
            TLSClientConfig:       &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
        }
    } else {
        transport = &http.Transport{
            DialContext:           (&net.Dialer{Timeout: timeout, KeepAlive: 10 * timeout}).DialContext,
            DisableKeepAlives:     *closeConnections,
            TLSHandshakeTimeout:   timeout,
            ResponseHeaderTimeout: timeout,
        }
    }

    response, err := transport.RoundTrip(request)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Request failed:", err)
    }
    return response
}
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes don't. Incoming request is always the same (from file on disk, posted with cURL):

```
2023/02/03 16:32:48 Proxy engine ready and listen at :8080, global timeout: 5000 ms

2023/02/03 16:32:53 Getting relevant values from request body
2023/02/03 16:32:53 Group: TS1
2023/02/03 16:32:53 Order number: 500000639557
2023/02/03 16:32:53 Check if order can be processed in endpoint 1
2023/02/03 16:32:53 Order can be processed in endpoint 1
2023/02/03 16:32:53 Proxying request to endpoint 1
2023/02/03 16:32:53 POST http://endpoint1:40002/service HTTP/1.1, 200 OK

2023/02/03 16:32:54 Getting relevant values from request body
2023/02/03 16:32:54 Group: TS1
2023/02/03 16:32:54 Order number: 500000639557
2023/02/03 16:32:54 Check if order can be processed in endpoint 1
2023/02/03 16:32:54 Order can be processed in endpoint 1
2023/02/03 16:32:54 Proxying request to endpoint 1
2023/02/03 16:32:54 POST http://endpoint1:40002/service HTTP/1.1, 200 OK

2023/02/03 16:32:55 Getting relevant values from request body
2023/02/03 16:32:55 Group: TS1
2023/02/03 16:32:55 Order number: 500000639557
2023/02/03 16:32:55 Check if order can be processed in endpoint 1
2023/02/03 16:32:55 Order can be processed in endpoint 1
2023/02/03 16:32:55 Proxying request to endpoint 1
2023/02/03 16:32:55 Request failed: EOF // exception from handleRequest function
2023/02/03 16:32:55 Response is nil :(
```

Does anyone know, what is going on and can help? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot determine the validity of the response by checking null, you must check the error. You are also not cloning the request or fixing the headers -- if you want a reverse proxy, use the `httputil.ReverseProxy`. It may not be related, but you are creating and discarding the `http.Transport` for each request, which is going to leak connections whenever `*closeConnections` is not `true`, but is otherwise wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

I've modify handleRequest, now it is running as goroutine:

```
func (h handler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // [...]
    ch := make(chan *http.Response)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)

    timeout := time.Duration(time.Duration(*globalTimeout).Milliseconds())
    go handleRequest(r, timeout, ch, &wg)

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()

    var resp *http.Response = <-ch

    if resp != nil {
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        log.Printf("%s %s %v, %s", r.Method, r.URL.String(), r.Proto, resp.Status)
        // [...]
    }
}

func handleRequest(request *http.Request, timeout time.Duration, ch chan *http.Response, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer (*wg).Done()

    transport := &http.Transport{
        DialContext:           (&net.Dialer{Timeout: timeout, KeepAlive: 10 * timeout}).DialContext,
        DisableKeepAlives:     *closeConnections,
        TLSHandshakeTimeout:   timeout,
        ResponseHeaderTimeout: timeout,
        TLSClientConfig:       &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }

    response, err := transport.RoundTrip(request)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Request failed:", err)
    }
    ch <- response
}
```

Now each request is served by separate thread, my parallel stress tests are 100% accurate.